# Pass an event into a constructor

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have a class that I want to be able the handle the mouse up event for a grid.

I tried to create it with a static method call like this:

```
MyDataBinding.BindObjectsToDataGrid(ListOfObjectsToBind, myGrid.MouseUp);
```

The end goal being that in the method I would assign a delegate to the MouseUp

```
PassedInMouseUp += myMethodThatWillHandleTheMouseUp;
```

Looks good here (to me) but the compiler chokes on the first line.  It says that I can only use MouseUp with a += or a -=.

Clearly I am going about this the wrong way.  How can I get a different class to handle the mouse up with out having to:

- Pass in the whole grid
- Expose the method that will be handling the mouse up as a public method.

Or, is this just a limitation and I will have to do one of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without reflection.

Like properties, .Net events compile to a pair of accessor methods - `add_EventName` and `remove_EventName`.  There is nothing that you can pass as an argument.

Comment: Maybe I could make a delegate that will add method to the event and then pass that into the method.  (To be called later.)  Would that work?  --- (Better yet I will go try it)

Comment: That would work.  `MyDataBinding.BindObjectsToDataGrid(ListOfObjectsToBind, h => myGrid.MouseUp += h);`.  The parameter would be an `Action<MouseEventHandler>`.